Relation between formation of carbocation and availability of nucleophile
Many sources suggest that in SN1 reactions the leaving group first exits the molecule, and the resulting carbocation is subsequently attacked by the nucleophile, suggesting that there is no relation between presence of nucleophile and carbocation formation.
If this is true, does the compound exist as a carbocation in absence of a nucleophile?

Not exactly. These mechanisms are generally somewhat mixed with each other.

@Mithoron Hmm that's what I thought. Could you perhaps cite some sources?
